# Grepping for whole words containing only numbers

Tags: regex, unix, grep, pattern-matching

I am trying to `grep` lines that contain words consisting in just digits.

So given a sample file like this:

```
abcd
abcd 123
adef1234
```

I am looking to output the line `abcd 123` and assign it to a variable. I tried the below:

```
grep -w '^[0-9]$' test_file.txt
```

But its not working. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: When you say "it's not working", how exactly is it not working?  Are you getting incorrect results?  What is incorrect?  What results do you get and how do they different from what you expected?

Comment: @fedorqui What is want is to print lines which have words whose characters are only digits.

Comment: @Andy Lester The error was that I was not getting any output.

Comment: OK now I see. I edited the question with some rewording. Removing my previous comment

Comment: Are letters, spaces and digits the only characters that can appear in your input file? If now, provide sample input that shows a more diverse set of ways in which the digits-only strings can appear (e.g. if `abcd 123.` exists in the input, does that match your desired regexp or not?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In grep `^` and `$` match start and end of *line* even if there is `-w` flag enabled. And you need to enable extended regexps (`-E` flag) to use `+`. Try

```
grep -E -w '[0-9]+' test_file.txt
```

Comment: Nice. Another option: `grep '\<[[:digit:]]\+\>'`

Comment: `^` and `$` match start and end of _string_, not _line_.That means they only match start and end of line if the strings you are testing do not contain newlines. AFAIK there's no option [yet] for grep to support multi-line regexp matching but there is for sed, awk, etc. so it's important for people to be aware of the true definition of those 2 meta-chars across all regexp engines.

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks. This is a bad wording on my side. From [`man grep`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep): _"match the empty string at the beginning and end of a line"_.

Comment: Yeah, technically that's true for `grep` given it processes one line at a time but it's just not what those meta-chars mean. I wouldn't bring it up but that misinterpretation of what those chars mean causes a lot of confusion with people using other tools. Maybe just add an "in grep" somewhere on that first line? Or leave it alone, whatever you prefer...